# Batch file "net use *:" user and password autofill

Tags: batch-file, cmd, net-use

is possible create batch file, that run command `net use s: *some address*` and then autofill the username and password?

Something like this:

```
if exist net use s: /delete
set USER=userid
set PASS=password

net use s: *some address*
```

Now cmd say "Enter username for *some address*"

And I need a %USER% variable to be automatically inserted into the username request. Same with password.

Something like this:

```
if exist net use s: /delete

set USER=userid
set PASS=password

net use s: *some address*
```

> Enter user name for *some address*:

```
echo %USER%
```

> Enter password for *some address*:

```
echo %PASS%
```

I know there is a command `net use s: *some address* password /USER:user /PERSISTENT:YES`
But this not working for me. I have error 1312.

The above works, but I dont want writing username and password every time I run this batch file. 
It is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

persistent param is for remembering the drive, for saving credentials use savecred, for example:

```
net use x: \\server\bla pwd123 /user:domain\username123 /savecred /p:yes
```

Comment: On an updated version of Windows 10 this command returns an error that conflicting switches were used.